# How to open same document as duplicate window in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

All I want is to have two different windows of the same document but at different zoom percentage that updates change in real-time, like one in 500% zoom for detailing work and other at 100% for the final result.

Comment: The [navigator panel](http://bit.ly/2BVSfCM) might be enough for what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

1. Windows > Arrange > New window for (last option)
2. Right click on newly created window > Move to new window
3. Resize and zoom the way you want it.